# Spoiler: "A Boy and His Blob" (Wii), why the I - III and IV - VI in the final bonus level?

Tags: nintendo-wii, a-boy-and-his-blob

## Spoiler Alert!

---

In `A Boy and His Blob` for the Nintendo Wii, the final bonus stage of the game opens with three doors labeled 1 - 3 in roman numbers (I, II, and III). Each door goes to a sortof "mini-bonus level". COmpleting any of these "mini-bonus" levels leaves you to choose from three *more* doors, 4 - 6 (IV, V, or VI). Completing any of these tree leaves you with one final puzzle (the same one regardless of the choices made) to get the golden jellybean and complete the level.

My question is: what gives? Why is this bonus level unlike all the others? I beat it easily the first time (by using door 1 and then door 3) and instantly suspected there must be something more. I have since been through every door in this level and haven't found any point. What am I missing? Or am I just over-analyzing this? :-)

Comment: The problem about this question is that unless there is a significant reason for why the level was structured like this, it's a question about design choice and so it's subjective. We wouldn't actually know the answer unless we developed the game.

Comment: @Mana -- or, unless doing the levels in a specific order or something unlocks more bonus content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-analyzing. There's no extra bonus content to be found in going through the doors in a specific order. I finally went through and got to this level, and then went through all the doors in every possible sequence. Nothing special happened.

Not sure why it was designed like this, though. Maybe to give some extra variety to the game? I'd have to get in touch with the developers.

Comment: I haven't played this game, but it reminds me of in Super Mario RPG, they have a set of numbered doors in one of the dungeons. There's nothing special to any order - they're just used to signify different doors. This sounds pretty much like the same thing.

Comment: Hey, I remember that part! Bowser's Castle, wasn't it? That part was frustrating.

Comment: Thanks Mana! I think you're right, I was just hoping there was some extra content to be found. It was such a great game, I was just looking for things that weren't there :-)